# Error of polygon

Tags: arcmap, polygon, gap

[image]How to find errors in polygons, such as likely gaps but not, but can't use the topology tool at ArcGIS, because the error results are not the error I want to find. So one polygon should overlap with the previous polygon, but even the polygon line shifts and separates with the previous polygon.
More or less the picture as follows.
[image]

Comment: so I've completed  the topology in arcgis, and the 'must not have gaps' error results that I get don't match the results that should be.
because one polygon should not move from the other polygon.

Comment: Actually I want to find errors anywhere in the many polygons that I have, for example polygons that shift so that they are separated from the polygons next to them. I think a lot of polygons are shifting, but is there a way to detect separate polygons or polygons with errors from all the data I have? in addition to using the topology method?

Comment: the one with the yellow dot should be connected to the polygon next to it, i just added a new photo

Comment: so I have digitized an area and received feedback from my superiors, I think during the digitization process I also did a split process which allowed the digitization of my polygons to have an error such as shifting polygon, because a large area is very difficult to do manually to find the error, so maybe there is a way for error detection in polygons that should merge with the next polygon?

Comment: You can try [Integrate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) but backup your data before you do. The tool will modify it

Comment: okey thank you for your consideration:)